# Using Powerquery to extract hierarchy from Excel indent

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am using a business application that exports `.xls` data files for analysis. I want to import these into Excel using `PowerQuery`.

There is a hierarchy to the data, but it is signified only by the indent of the `first column`. There are no leading zeros or other characters.

`Powerquery M` doesn't seem to have a function to return the indent level.

Other approaches I've found rely on counting leading zeros, but that won't work for me.

Along the way, I have written a simple Excel custom function using the Cell.IndentLevel attribute works well enough, but I'd like to get PowerQuery to do this so there is just one import code.

Q: Can Powerquery **access the Excel cell**.`indentlevel` value? Or can it execute a custom Excel function? How else might I approach this?

Comment: If the file is an .xlsx or .xlsm file, it is really a zip file containing a number of xml files. You would have to write a PQ function to access these directly, and then you could sort out the style property from that information.  I think it would be **MUCH** simpler to just use your Excel function, and add a "helper column" to your data that translates indentlevel to hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Ron Rosenfield mentioned quite rightly that this indent issue may be Excel Based, Doesn't look like Power query has an indent handler.

This is likely because Excel Indent Level is not an ISO method of Data heirarchy.

So you can just apply a helper column that will brute force give the level of indent then power query can take care of the rest.

This should do it, modify as you need  and it will detect and apply a number

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim MyCell As Variant
    Range("A:A").Insert
    For Each MyCell In Range("A1:A10") 'Change this to be Dynamic
        MyCell.Value = MyCell.Offset(, 1).IndentLevel
    Next MyCell
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Oooh also staging stoof from external... "**Transform**" Part of ETL *(Extract, Transform, Load)* Well, Most of the time indents are handled by spaces.

Do you have any other options than XLS, as the indent may be handled differently in CSV.

In the un-ironically named, **Transform Tab of the Power Query ribbon** you can use **Split Columns** by the Delimiter Space. (One of the more common delimiters for indent besides Tab.)

This will then allow you to group the data, a little messy if there are other spaces but you can make steps to handle that

Alternatively there are other options in the Transform Tab you can use failing that, as there is no example of the system you are exporting from it's difficult to say if this is an Excel Indent or if Indent actually applies.

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: The OP stated that data was segregated by the Indent Level; **not** by leading spaces.

Comment: Without Seeing OP Example of indent it is difficult to handle, usually programatic Indents are done by leading Spaces or leading Tab both of these are handled in PQ. So it would be interesting to see where the data is coming from if there is an alternative which is breaking PQ.

Comment: In Excel, IndentLevel is a property of the range object.  It has nothing to do with tabs or spaces.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Excels functionality in this regard, however, OP stated this data is ETL `"using a business application that exports .xls data files for analysis"`. so Excel may not be handling them as indent levels at all. I have modified my post to highlight that, because I noticed I made the assumption others would know that.

Comment: The OP writes that his working VBA routine is using the  `Cell.IndentLevel` attribute

Comment: When you're right you're right, I have modified the post to include a method of capturing that Puts a helper column in A and then just iterates down giving the indent level as it goes, nothing too fancy but you can use it in power query after :) Popped you in as an edit note at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately the business application only exports in XLS (not even XLSX).

The suggestion of trying to extract the XML/ZIP is interesting but I agree that seems a lot of work.

While I can use the VBA macro or my custom function to insert a helper column, and then transform using PQ I was hoping to be able to do all in PQ for simplicity and portability. It might be my best bet for now.

Comment: Sorry, mate I had a good workshop of the issue tried different exports and imports, looks like PQ doesn't recognise the Indent, this is probably because it is a Cell Property and not actually part fo the data :( so VBA looks like the viable ETL.  Out of curiosity do you have access to the raw tables this is formed from?

Comment: Thanks for trying Xyloz. Unfortunately there is no direct access to the raw tables. I may need to think a bit laterally on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffering the same trouble.
I can solve only that:

```
    Sub level2_for_transfer_data_from1C_to_powerquery()

    For Each cell In Selection
        i = 0
        Do While i < cell.IndentLevel
            cell.Value = "_" & cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next cell
    End Sub

Adn after that I part the data by delimiter '_'
```